# Dotnet CLI - Adding Wix Projects to a solution on the command line

Tags: c#, command-line, wix, dotnet-cli

I am trying to add a wix project to an existing solution using the  dotnet CLI command line.

```
dotnet sln add <project-name>.csproj
```

works fine

```
dotnet sln add <project-name>.wixproj
```

returns with an error -

" has an unknown project type and cannot be added to the solution file. Contact your SDK provider for support."

I have the wix toolset installed because I can add wix projects easily in visual studio - but I specifically need to do this on the command line.  Any ideas?

I am expecting the command to add the project to the solution like the normal csprojs

Comment: Is your .wixproj  wix v3 or v4?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I think I have got the solution now.  dotnet did not recognise the project type but adding this to the project file fixed it - 
```
<ProjectTypeGuids>930C7802-8A8C-48F9-8165-68863BCCD9DD</ProjectTypeGuids>
```